# preventDefault is not working when i submitting form using onclick event in submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is function `handle()` which is called by `onclick` event.

```
function handler(identifier, e) {
    var datastring = $('form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "core.php?type=" + identifier,
        data: datastring,
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

And whenever I'm submitting my form ajax call in not working.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">   
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="handler('login')">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an `onsubmit` handler on the form itself and let us know how you get on.

EDIT: I notice that you are also not passing the event to your event handler, you can do so with the following: `onclick="handler('login', event)"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not working in my case.

Comment: Thank you I just check Its my fault Iam using `onsubmit="handler('login', event)"`instead of `onclick="handler('login', event)"`